# Rails Arel selecting distinct columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I've hit a slight block with the new `scope` methods (Arel 0.4.0, Rails 3.0.0.rc)

Basically I have:

A `topics` model, which `has_many :comments`, and a `comments` model (with a `topic_id` column) which `belongs_to :topics`.

I'm trying to fetch a collection of "Hot Topics", i.e. the topics that were most recently commented on. Current code is as follows:

```
# models/comment.rb
scope :recent, order("comments.created_at DESC")

# models/topic.rb
scope :hot, joins(:comments) & Comment.recent & limit(5)
```

If I execute `Topic.hot.to_sql`, the following query is fired:

```
SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "comments"
ON "comments"."topic_id" = "topics"."id"
ORDER BY comments.created_at DESC LIMIT 5
```

This works fine, but it potentially returns duplicate topics - If topic #3 was recently commented on several times, it would be returned several times.

**My question**

How would I go about returning a distinct set of topics, bearing in mind that I still need to access the `comments.created_at` field, to display how long ago the last post was? I would imagine something along the lines of `distinct` or `group_by`, but I'm not too sure how best to go about it.

Any advice / suggestions are much appreciated - I've added a 100 rep bounty in hopes of coming to an elegant solution soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1**

This doesn't use Arel, but Rails 2.x syntax:

```
Topic.all(:select => "topics.*, C.id AS last_comment_id, 
                       C.created_at AS last_comment_at",
          :joins => "JOINS (
             SELECT DISTINCT A.id, A.topic_id, B.created_at
             FROM   messages A,
             (
               SELECT   topic_id, max(created_at) AS created_at
               FROM     comments
               GROUP BY topic_id
               ORDER BY created_at
               LIMIT 5
             ) B
             WHERE  A.user_id    = B.user_id AND 
                    A.created_at = B.created_at
           ) AS C ON topics.id = C.topic_id
          "
).each do |topic|
  p "topic id: #{topic.id}"
  p "last comment id: #{topic.last_comment_id}"
  p "last comment at: #{topic.last_comment_at}"
end
```

Make sure you index the `created_at` and `topic_id` column in the `comments` table.

**Solution 2**

Add a `last_comment_id` column in your `Topic` model. Update the `last_comment_id` after creating a comment. This approach is much faster than using complex SQL to determine the last comment.

E.g:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :last_comment, :class_name => "Comment"
  scope :hot, joins(:last_comment).order("comments.created_at DESC").limit(5)
end

class  Comment
  belongs_to :topic

  after_create :update_topic

  def update_topic
    topic.last_comment = self
    topic.save
    # OR better still
    # topic.update_attribute(:last_comment_id, id)
  end
end
```

This is much efficient than running a complex SQL query to determine the hot topics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it's a solution, but I'm really only looking for one that uses Rails3/Arel `scope`!

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer and awarding the bounty to you - It's doesn't answer my initial question, but it actually works better this way anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: Would it be overkill to use transactions for this type of thing?

Comment: This works better, but it is possible to use .uniq in Rails 3.2.1, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq

Comment: You should be able to add `uniq`. Did you run in to any issues?

Answer (score 3):

This is not that elegant in most SQL implementations. One way is to first get the list of the five most recent comments grouped by topic_id. Then get the comments.created_at by sub selecting with the IN clause.

I'm very new to Arel but something like this could work

```
recent_unique_comments = Comment.group(c[:topic_id]) \
                                .order('comments.created_at DESC') \
                                .limit(5) \
                                .project(comments[:topic_id]
recent_topics = Topic.where(t[:topic_id].in(recent_unique_comments))

# Another experiment (there has to be another way...)

recent_comments = Comment.join(Topic) \
                         .on(Comment[:topic_id].eq(Topic[:topic_id])) \ 
                         .where(t[:topic_id].in(recent_unique_comments)) \
                         .order('comments.topic_id, comments.created_at DESC') \
                         .group_by(&:topic_id).to_a.map{|hsh| hsh[1][0]}
```

Comment: Thanks - it's definitely a solution, but it's not quite ideal. The topics are returned in arbitrary order, and I won't be able to access the time of the last comment - hence my attempt at a table join. Is there no way to group my original query to return distinct results? I feel like it's almost there, just not quite.

Comment: Ah, then I only solved at most half your problem. The easiest way might be to get all the comments for the unique recent topics and then only show the latest. The SQL to do this is often ridden with vendor specific solutions. There's most probably an ANSI SQL way of doing this but I actually doubt Arel supports it. Hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In order to accomplish this you need to have a scope with a `GROUP BY` to get the latest comment for each topic. You can then order this scope by `created_at` to get the most recent commented on topics.

The following works for me using sqlite

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :topic

  scope :recent, order("comments.created_at DESC")
  scope :latest_by_topic, group("comments.topic_id").order("comments.created_at DESC")
end


class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  scope :hot, joins(:comments) & Comment.latest_by_topic & limit(5)
end
```

I used the following seeds.rb to generate the test data

```
(1..10).each do |t|
  topic = Topic.new
  (1..10).each do |c|
    topic.comments.build(:subject => "Comment #{c} for topic #{t}")
  end
  topic.save
end
```

And the following are the test results

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Topic.hot.map(&:id)
 => [10, 9, 8, 7, 6] 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Topic.first.comments.create(:subject => 'Topic 1 - New comment')
 => #<Comment id: 101, subject: "Topic 1 - New comment", topic_id: 1, content: nil, created_at: "2010-08-26 10:53:34", updated_at: "2010-08-26 10:53:34"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Topic.hot.map(&:id)
 => [1, 10, 9, 8, 7] 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >
```

The SQL generated for sqlite(reformatted) is extremely simple and I hope Arel would render different SQL for other engines as this would certainly fail in many DB engines as the columns within Topic are not in the "Group by list". If this did present a problem then you could probably overcome it by limiting the selected columns to just comments.topic_id

```
puts Topic.hot.to_sql
SELECT     "topics".* 
FROM       "topics" 
INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."topic_id" = "topics"."id" 
GROUP BY  comments.topic_id 
ORDER BY  comments.created_at DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Awesome - I haven't had time to test it yet, but it looks perfect. I'm using sqlite in development, but potentially mysql in production, so I'll have to test how it translates - Will respond soon.

Comment: How will you get the created_date of the last comment for a topic in this approach?

Comment: It seems that the reduced GROUP BY syntax is MySQL specific http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: Your answer definitely helped me a lot - but I ended up going with KandadaBoggu's solution, so I'd think it's only fair to award him the bounty! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was about Arel, I thought I'd add this in, since Rails 3.2.1 adds `uniq` to the QueryMethods:

If you add `.uniq` to the Arel it adds `DISTINCT` to the `select` statement.

e.g. `Topic.hot.uniq`

Also works in scope:

e.g. `scope :hot, joins(:comments).order("comments.created_at DESC").limit(5).uniq`

So I would assume that

```
scope :hot, joins(:comments) & Comment.recent & limit(5) & uniq
```

should also probably work.

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq