# Rails - retrieve distinct records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, distinct

I have the following has_many and belongs_to relationship:

```
class Trophy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :awards
end

class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trophy
end
```

The Award model has a `user_id` field and a `trophy_id` field.

**For an instance of a trophy, I want to return the 5 most recent, but distinct user awards.**

I could do:

```
def recent_awards
  trophy_awards = awards.recent.includes(:user)
  trophy_awards.uniq! {|a| a.user_id}
  trophy_awards[0...4]
end
```

However, it's not efficient because I'm dealing with a lot of records.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
def recent_awards
  trophy_awards = awards.limit(50).recent.includes(:user)
  trophy_awards.uniq! {|a| a.user_id}
  trophy_awards[0...4]
end
```

Problem is, it won't give me 5 distinct user awards if the last 48 awards were to the same user.

*What's the best way to go about returning the 5 most recent, but distinct user awards?*

Comment: Oh man, this is an awesome SQL question, I am going to have to dust off a part of my brain I haven't used in a little while...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125209/how-to-fetch-distinct-values-with-arel-relational-algebra-and-has-many-through

Answer (score 2):

```
def recent_awards
  awards.limit(5).recent.includes(:user).uniq
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq

Comment: OP already tried that, said it grabs too many records from the database. OP only wants to get five records from the query itself.

Comment: Maybe pedantic, but I think maybe `awards.includes(:user).recent.uniq.limit(5)` reads a little nicer...

Comment: this doesn't return unique award records based on the user_id in the awards table...

Comment: Based on "For an instance of a trophy, I want to return the 5 most recent, but distinct user awards", I didn't realize that was a requirement. It would be easy to restrict to a particular user_d with a `where`, but it might be better if you can structure it like `user.trophy.limit(5).recent.includes(:user).uniq.awards`, or something... Not enough details about your relationships to guess, but it should be pretty easy to change. Either way, `.uniq` will retrieve distinct records.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Award.find_by_sql("SELECT *
  FROM awards a1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(created_at) AS recent
    FROM awards
    GROUP BY user_id) a2
  ON (a1.created_at = a2.recent)
  ORDER BY a1.created_at DESC
  LIMIT 5;")
```

Comment: this is giving me postgres syntax errors...should have said i'm using postgres

Comment: @keruilin, I edited the answer. A version of this modified for my project worked for me, check it out and let me know if I need to make any other changes.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't throw an error, but actually I'm not sure if it is going to get you the most recent ones :(